# Grid columns: Use space available

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, windows-phone-8, grid

I have a grid with 2 columns.

Colum1 | Column2
Name     Button

The button should always be aligned to the right and fully visible.
The name should be an the left, and can take as much space as available.

Comment: You'll want to review the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207042(v=vs.105).aspx) for layout on MSDN. It covers this and many more topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` says to take as much space as available

`Auto` says to take such amount of space that internal controls are needed to display

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```